# Inconsistent behaviour of exists() function in R

Tags: r, exists

In two different functions, the exactly same exists () call behaves in different ways. One works and the other does not. The working one requires only one argument. The other one requires three.

Until yesterday, both functions worked out. Just before clossing session, I intalled some packages. And today, when I ran the code with the functions  again, one of them was working and the other wasn't. So, I detached most of running packages for not to blame one of them. But the issue was still there.

Working one:

`fun1<-function(arg1,...) { if(!exists(as.character(substitute(arg1)))) return ("Some sttuf") }`

Not-working one:

`fun2<-function(arg1, arg2, arg3, ...) { if(!exists(as.character(substitute(arg1))) ) return ("Some sttuf") }`

Does the fact of more than one argument in fun2 have something to do with this inconsistent behavior? It is not possible to build a list or vector with args since an non-existent object generates an error before the list is built.

Any ideas why this could be happening? And more important: any ideas on how to troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: Maybe use `missing` instead of `exists`? Otherwise, could you add a working example of the function that can be tested?

Answer (score 0):

If you only supply one argument, the function that requires three arguments will not work, this is expected.

One way to deal with this is to specify the function you want to use explicitly.

For example, if you want to use exists() from {elasticsearch} rather than {base}, you should specify as

```
elasticsearch::exists()
```